# How can I apply rigid body to multi-part object using array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, rigidbody

I made apple. It has two parts, stem and body.

I used array modifier to make copies of the apple (because rigid body doesn't works with array modifier).
Then, converted it to mesh and tried to "Seperate By Loose Parts" in edit mode.

It seperated apples well but apple's body and stem has seperated too!
Because Apple has two parts, stem and body.

How can I make copies of object that has multiple parts using array modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to use linked data.

1. Select the apple.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>  and move the apple in the new position as it was in array modifier. (instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>  creates linked copies of apple, so that when you change one, the second changes also)
3. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>R</kbd> to repeat this action quickly.

Alternatively, if you have a lot of objects already

1. Select all bodies without stem.
2. Press right mouse button, and in connect menu, select Set Origin → to Geometry.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  This will link all body models. Now you can add stem to one of them and all of them will get it.

Alternatively, you can connect steam to body using one edge. Select one vertex on the stem and one on the body and press F. This hack tells Blender that these two parts are connected, so that they will not be separated by loose parts.